Difference between two variables from different dates
Using Crystal Reports
I want to be able to get the difference from the last date of the year and the first date of the year for each year of units.  Group1 is for parameters only.  Group2 is the unit and group 3 is the year. I created a formula to retreive the odometer on the 1st day of the year and a formula to retrieve the odometer for the last day of the year. Finally I have a formula that calculates the difference between both odometers for each year which I inserted in the GF3 but it is not working.
enter image description here
In the picture, I have a column for the date, the actual odometer at time of date, the formula for the first date, the formula for the last date, the formula for the difference and one for the type of transaction which I use in filters only.
The details section is visible for this question but is suppressed for the report.
+

I finally figured it out.  I added a min and max in the group footer then created a formula that calculates the difference between the two dates.
